# Google InAppBilling - How to test if non-consumable purchase has been refunded?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented Google Play Games in-app billing into my Android app using their InAppBilling library. The purchase flow works fine, but the problem is when I issue a refund (and revoke the license) via the Google Play Console. Here's how I check the purchase:

```
Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_FULLVER);

if (purchase == null)
{
    globals.purchased = false;
}
else
{
    globals.purchased = true;
    globals.purchaseState = purchase.getPurchaseState();
}
```

I would have thought that either ~

A: a refund + revoke results in a null purchase object
or
B: the getPurchaseState returns a value relating to the purchase either "not purchased", "purchase completed", or "refunded". However, the purchase state is null when no purchase has taken place, then always zero when purchased or refunded. Does anyone have any pointers? I've already wasted many hours trying to solve this.

Comment: This seems to be not documented very well. Do you get a json object named `purchaseState` when you call `purchase.getOriginalJson()`? This should return 1 if the product is cancelled according to documentation I found.

Comment: The getPurchaseState() method in the Purchase class does exactly that - it returns the purchaseState value from the original JSON.